# What's the most elegant / efficient way to find all values in a range in PHP, with mixed alphanumeric bounds?

Tags: php, algorithm, range

Given 2 strings, find all values in the range between them:

```
find_range('1', '5') = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
find_range('A', 'E') = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
find_range('001', '005') = ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005'];
find_range('1A', '5A') = ['1A', '2A', '3A', '4A', '5A'];
find_range('GG1', 'GG5') = ['GG1', 'GG2', 'GG3', 'GG4', 'GG5'];
find_range('A1A', 'A5A') = ['A1A', 'A2A', 'A3A', 'A4A', 'A5A'];
find_range('1A', '1E') = ['1A', '1B', '1C', '1D', '1E'];

find_range('1', 'F') = null; // or exception
```

Any suggestions on the best way to write the find_range method?

Comment: Why is it being downvoted?

Comment: @zerkms Because a lot of SO users are way too trigger happy with the downvote button.

Comment: I'd suggest by using PHP's perl style character incrementing: without any kind of error checking, `function find_range($from, $to) { $to++; $result = []; while ($from !== $to) { $result[] = $from++; } return $result; }`

Comment: @zerkms the OP doesn't show any efforts or code so **-1**

Comment: @HamZa: to be fair OP didn't ask about implementation but about algorithm. So +1

Comment: @zerkms Even when asking for an algorithm one should show their way to the solution and why/how it has failed. This is typically a `give me the code` question.

Comment: @HamZa: it doesn't look givemethecode-like question for me. "one should show their way to the solution" --- one might be not experienced enough to think of one. There are cases when you just don't know how and where to start.

Comment: `find_range('A1A', 'A3E') = ????`

Comment: @MarkBaker You'd *think* that might be a good idea; depending on the range, however, [it might not](http://3v4l.org/b4mJS).

Comment: `find_range('1', 'F') = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];`  There's way too many possibilities until you lock down more of the output, which should then suggest the implementation.  Why doesn't `find_range('A1A', 'A5A')` include `A1B`, `A1C`, etc?  When you mix types like this, you probable need to specify incrementing patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the naive implementation:

```
var_dump(find_range('1', '5'));
var_dump(find_range('A', 'E'));
var_dump(find_range('001', '005'));
var_dump(find_range('1A', '5A'));
var_dump(find_range('GG1', 'GG5'));
var_dump(find_range('A1A', 'A5A'));
var_dump(find_range('1A', '1E'));

try {
    var_dump(find_range('1', 'F'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

function find_range($from, $to)
{
    $begin = $end = null;
    foreach (str_split($from) as $i => $c) {
        if ($c != $to[$i] && $begin === null) {
            $begin = $i;
        } elseif ($c == $to[$i] && $begin !== null) {
            $end = $i;
        }
    }

    $prefix = $suffix = '';

    if ($end !== null) {
        $suffix = substr($from, $end - strlen($from));
    } else {
        $end = strlen($from) - 1;
    }

    if ($begin === null) {
        return null;
    }

    if ($begin > 0) {
        $prefix = substr($from, 0, $begin);
    }

    $dataBegin = substr($from, $begin, $end - $begin + 1);
    $dataEnd = substr($to, $begin, $end - $begin + 1);

    if (ctype_digit($dataBegin) !== ctype_digit($dataEnd) || ctype_alpha($dataBegin) !== ctype_alpha($dataEnd)) {
        throw new Exception('Incompatible types');
    }

    $range = range($dataBegin, $dataEnd);

    $rangeDecorated = array_map(function($i) use($prefix, $suffix) {
        return $prefix . $i . $suffix;
    }, $range);

    return $rangeDecorated;
}
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/y41Hdz

Not sure if it makes sense to explain anything here since the code is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: And as usually - I'm keen to hear on the reasons I was downvoted (in case if there are one)